# Not able to use TVP with dynamic SQL query

Tags: sql-server

i am trying to insert values in TVP(table valued parameter) variable using dynamic query and passing TVP values into procedure. 
I am getting the error as-- Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the table variable "@EmpDetailsTVP1".
Dont understand where i am wrong ,i have already declared TVP above
Here 
 ee12345 is TVP table parameter
cp1122334 is proc

```
declare @vsql1 as nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @EmpDetailsTVP1 AS ee12345
set @vsql1='INSERT INTO @EmpDetailsTVP1(ei,en,enm)
           select EmpId1, EmpName1, [Role1] from EmployeeDetails2 '
exec sys.sp_executesql
    @vsql1
EXEC cp1122334 @EmpDetailsTVP
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope of a table variable is the scope in which is declared.  To load the table variable and then pass it as a TVP. just omit the dynamic SQL so it's in the same scope as the declare:

```
DECLARE @vsql1 AS nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @EmpDetailsTVP1 AS ee12345;
INSERT INTO @EmpDetailsTVP1(ei,en,enm)
    SELECT EmpId1, EmpName1, [Role1] FROM dbo.EmployeeDetails2;
EXEC cp1122334 @EmpDetailsTVP;
```

Comment: thanx for the solution..but i have 2 doubts
1--I use to pass values to TVP outside proc,
 here i passing values to TVP inside the proc but i havnt done this practise earlier.
 will it work?
2--as TVp are readonly in SQL SERVER if i wanna use them with dynamic sql,it is 
going out of scope as you suggested me solution,but there is no method to make it globally 
accessible in proc.like using # or ## to make it global

Comment: but more than 2100 parameters cannot be inserted this way

Answer (score 0):

`Dynamic query` will have different `session` so you cannot use table variable declared outside of dynamic query,

Instead you can create a `temp table` as same structure of `TVP`.

```
Create table #temp(ei datatype,en datatype...) -- As like `TVP(ee12345)`

declare @vsql1 as nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @EmpDetailsTVP1 AS ee12345
```

Insert into `temp table(#temp)` instead of `TVP` which can be accessed inside  Dynamic query

```
set @vsql1='INSERT INTO #temp(ei,en,enm)
           select EmpId1, EmpName1, [Role1] from EmployeeDetails2 '
exec sys.sp_executesql @vsql1
```

Now insert the records back to the `TVP`

```
Insert into @EmpDetailsTVP (ei,en,enm)
select ei,en,enm from #temp

EXEC cp1122334 @EmpDetailsTVP
```

Comment: @Thanx NoDisplayName your solution works. Now i have better understanding of TVp scopes.but i have 1 doubts----I use to pass values to TVP outside proc, here i passing values to TVP inside the proc but i havnt done this practise earlier. will it work..with the sme ame way as you have suggested to go global #temp then TVP then finally into proc???